# MAKING SUGGESTIONS - It+ MODAL + be a good idea to +infinitive (What Modals can logically be used with this structure)

Tags: grammar, word-usage

"It might be a good idea to get home early."

With this basic structure for offering a suggestion, we have the modal "might". Am I able to use other modals to communicate a suggestion in common usage here?

Comment: The whole thing about making suggestions is that you can express them in a lot of different ways. You can be very tentative and polite ("It could be"); or you can be more direct ("It would be").